How to handle CrudRepository exceptions with showing error message on page from where the form was submitted?
The function below handles form submission to change a user data in the database (save, delete):
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String manageUser(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Long userId = Long.valueOf(formData.getFirst("userId"));
    Long id = Long.valueOf(formData.getFirst("id"));
    String username = formData.getFirst("username");
    String password = formData.getFirst("password");
    User changedUserData = new User(id, username, password);
    List<Role> roles = Arrays.stream(formData.getFirst("roles").split(","))
            .map(roleName -> new Role(0L, changedUserData, roleName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    changedUserData.setRoles(roles);
    String actionName = formData.getFirst(ACTION_SAVE) != null ? ACTION_SAVE : ACTION_DELETE;
    if (ACTION_SAVE.equals(actionName)) {
        userRepository.save(changedUserData);
    } else if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(actionName)) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
    return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("referer");
}

I use userRepository.save(changedUserData). This function doesn't throw any excpetions to find out whether there are any errors or not. I have read something about Spring's "exception translating mechanism" but I don't know how to apply it in my situation.
I want that when an exception was thrown the error message is displayed on the page from where the form was submitted (passing as model attributes to Thymeleaf or redirecting with flash attributes).

Then you have to catch the error and pass it to the model, easy as that. But usually you wanna filter the error message to not reveal any sensitive backend data to the client.
